# QLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'invoice.posts' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts`

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

if I changed the name of this

```
'section_name' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
'discription' => 'required',
```

to this

```
'lolate' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
'body' => 'required',
```

it work and return this

```
The lolate field is required.
The body field is required
```

my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'section_name' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'discription' => 'required',
    ]);

    sections::create([
        'section_name'=>$request->section_name,
        'discription'=>$request->description,
        'Created_by'=>(Auth::user()->name)
    ]);
    session()->flash('add','تم إضافة القسم بنجاح');
    return redirect('/sections');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did you change the names of the fields being submitted to match the change you made?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here with `unique:posts` validation in the first edit you will not face any issue because it fails on the required condition, also you need to define the column to check it with unique validation, it will be something like this

`unique:posts,column`

I hope it's useful